# Why do some URLs in emails turn up clickable and others not? I have two different pages sending a link via email, but only one is clickable

Tags: email, clickable

All my registration pages successfully send clickable links via email (using Symfony). However, I have a mail opt in page that's has similar code, but the links aren't turning up as clickable.

I've now set up identical test emails on the mail optin php page and one of my registration pages, and am sending just the following in each email:

```
$body = "https://www.blahblahsite.com"
```

The sender, populated with the same code for each test, is:

```
if (!$result = AppEmail::sendEmail($to, $subject, $body, $from, null, null))
{
     //error handler
}
```

I've checked that my test code on each page is the same, yet one link still turns up not clickable.

The other factor is that I use gmail to send the emails:

```
$transport = Transport::fromDsn('smtp://myemail@blahblahsite.com:password_here@smtp.gmail.com:587?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login');
```

What other factors can determine whether a link arrives clickable please?

Thank you.

Comment: Most likely its too long. But anyway dont look at the code, look at the message. Whats different between the 2.

Comment: I've made it so that the test message being added to both emails is just $body = "https://www.blahblahsite.com"

Comment: You are looking at your code, the only thing the email clients see is the message, so the message *must* be different. Look at the message directly, most email clients allow you to see the raw message